# Formating Kindle Book in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, kindle

As anyone created a Kindle Book with LibreOffice?

I've been doing the following so far:

- Adding 0.40 of indentation on the first line of each paragraph.
- Setting line height to 1.5
- Justifying the text

Are there other suggestions?

If I save the book in .doc format does it display OK when turned into Kindle format?

Comment: Heard of the "Send-to-Kindle" email id facility? For instance, my kindle id is ahkkcr_47@kindle.com. If I create a .doc, and send it using my (say gmail) id to ahkkcr_47@kindle.com, it gets converted to a Kindle book and sits in the device. (But the Kindle needs to be connected to the internet) The "from" id has to be among the "approved" ids in your amazon account to which your kindle is linked. Find out more if needed on Amazon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Alkinea](http://soft.alkinea.net) it automatically converts a LibreOffice document to Kindle.
You can also find a template for a novel type of book here:
    http://soft.alkinea.net/doc_templates.html
This template shows recommended formatting for the paragraph indentation, line spacing, etc.
Try to do most of the formatting using styles.
I would suggest one style for the chapter titles (Headings 1) and another for the text itself (Text Body). 
On "Text Body" I would suggest an indent of 0.25" and justify the text.

This software uses "Kindlegen" to do the final conversion to kindle. You can find this software on Amazon's website.
You will also need to download Amazon's previewer.